# Retrieving JSON raw file data from Hive table

Tags: hive

I have a JSON File. I want to move only selected fields to Hive table. So below is the statement I used to create a new table to import the data from JSON file to HIVE Table. While creating it doesn't give any error but when i use select * from JsonFile1 or count(*) from JsonFile1 I get error as **Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer**
I have browsed over the internet stuck with this since few days. I can't find a solution. I checked in the HDFS. I see there is a table created and complete file imported as-is(not just the fields I selected but all of it). I just provided the sample data, the actual data contains like 50+ field names. creating all the column names is cumbersome. Is that what we need to do? Thank you in advance.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE JsonFile1(user STRUCT<id:BIGINT,description:STRING, followers_count:INT>) 
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'com.cloudera.hive.serde.JSONSerDe'
LOCATION 'link/data';
```

I have data as below

{filter_level":"low",geo":null,"user":{"id":859264394,"description":"I don’t want it. Building #techteam, #LetsTalk!!! def@abc.com",
"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","name"krogmi",
"screen_name":"jkrogmi","id_str":"859264394",}}06:20:16 +0000 2012","default_profile_image":false,"followers_count":88,
"profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDFFCC","screen_name":"abc_abc"}}

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. 
I have deleted the data in hdfs which I was pointing in the LOCATION '...', copied data again from local to hdfs and recreated the table again and it worked.
I am assuming that data was the problem.